# Run python unittest until it fails

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a Python `unittest.TestCase` that sometime fails.  To debug this, I would like to run automatically run it until it fails.  I found https://pypi.org/project/pytest-repeat/ which looks like what I am looking for, but it explicitly says

> Unfortunately pytest-repeat is not able to work with unittest.TestCase test classes. These tests will simply always run once, regardless of --count, and show a warning.

Is there something similar that works with `unittest`?

As I am writing this, it occurs to me that a simple shell command might be the solution:

```
while pytest ...
do
  echo Sadly, it passed again
done
```

Is that the actual solution, or is there some python tool that does what I want (possibly better in some way)?

Answer (score 0):

Could a simple `try` and `except` work?  Just have a `while(true)` loop with a `break` in the `except` statement.

I'm fairly new to python so apologies if the question is way above this answer.